# Using Swift Computed Properties Vs. Accessor and Mutator Functions

Tags: swift, performance

Coming from a Java background where getters and setters are commonly used to provide a public interface for private fields, I see computed properties in swift as an integrated modification of such accessor and mutator methods. I understand that computed properties are designed to modify or retrieve the value of any other field, while providing functionality for additional code. 
Given that Swift computed properties appear to have the same purpose and usage of Java getters and setters, would there be any significant performance difference in the following swift declarations? Is there any performance advantage using computed properties over accessors and mutators?

Computed property

```
    private var privateField: Int = 0

    var field: Int { get { return privateField } set { privateField = newValue } }
```

Getter / Setter

```
private var privateField: Int = 0

func getField() -> Int {
    return privateField
}

func setField(newValue: Int) {
    privateField = newValue
}
```

In terms of readability, I personally think the separate methods approach looks neater and more organized, and if there were no performance issues I would use it over `get {} set {}`

Comment: Removed `[java]` tag as it doesn't appear you want an answer about Java.

Comment: Don't. The getField/setField construct you have mentioned is probably a confusion from the history from Objective-C as that's how properties were declared, and it was ugly. With Swift, it means you do not have a field called "field", you have two methods called "getField" and "setField". Not very nice. And you can't use "willSet" and "didSet".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key here is to write idiomatic Swift code; a property in Swift is expected to be:

```
var field: Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        //Any consequences of setting here
    }
}
```

Your `getField()`/`setField()` solution is unusual and not an expected use of the language. Readability is the most important aspect here, but this aligns with performance: I'm sure as the language is further developed and optimized, it will definitely ensure that its own idiomatic code continues to run quickly, but it may not care about the performance of your `getField()`/`setField()`.